# Python: Accessing the variables from a Subprocess (Child) script, in the parent script

Tags: python, shell, output, abaqus

Using Python 2.7, I have a main script which executes a subprocess script. **My question is how do I capture certain variables from the subprocess**, e.g. the vectors:

```
vec_1, vec_2, vec_3
```

I know that it is possible to obtain the `stdout` from the script as matrix of characters using `subprocess.communicate()`, however that doesn't suit my intended purpose. Here is what I have tried so far.

The Parent Script:

```
import subprocess
if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = subprocess.Popen(["abaqus", "python", "childscript.py", \
        "file"], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    process.wait()
    pr = process.communicate()
```

Child Subprocess:

```
def function(a):
    return vec_1, vec_2, vec_3

if __name__ == '__main__':
    function()
```

Bonus marks if anyone has an idea how to execute the subprocess without using shell=True. It seems to only be possible with the shell as it involves executing a .bat file.

**EDIT**

TO clarify why I am not directly importing the function into the main script:

The program executed in the subprocess, Abaqus has it's own python interface and it allows a python script to be used to access it's data outputs. Hence, the python script should be run through the program and cannot be integrated into the main.

Comment: You can't do it with subprocess. Why don't you simply import and call the function? Check the multiprocessing module

Comment: even under multiprocessing you will still have to serialize your variables to pass them between processes... I assume you're trying to do some work in parallel?  otherwise there's not much point

Comment: Thanks for the response, but unfortunately that won't work as the subprocess executes a 3rd party program which runs the python script itself. Meaning it is not possible to integrate the child script into the main.

Comment: consider having the main routine run under abaqus as well, then you can call the sub as a function.

Comment: @KurzedMetal Multiprocessing in ABAQUS uses additional licences, which might be a problem, if you are already using all available/disposable licences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your interest, what I wanted to do is not possible. If it was simply a case of executing the child script along then Anentropic would be correct - the multiprocessing module is a better way to go.

As my question was regarding a 3rd party program that has a python interface, unfortunately it is not possible.

Reference: https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_I_access_the_ABAQUS_python_API_from_outside_ABAQUS_cae

Answer (score 0):

Messy method which might work for passing single values.......

```
import subprocess
if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = subprocess.Popen(["abaqus", "python", "child.py", \
        "file"], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    process.wait()
    x= process.stdout.read()
    exec(x)
    print vec_1
    print vec_2
```

Child.py:

```
def function(a):
    vec_1=a*2
    vec_2=a*3     
    print("vec_1=" + str(vec_1))
    print("vec_2=" + str(vec_2)) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num=4        
    function(num)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Doug. However, it's not really what I am looking for. Cheers.